# Looping through list till statement is true

Tags: python, list

I am trying to loop through an list item by item in python

Also i want to check if x is the item if yes i want to store the result into a new list and then print it.

This is the code that i tried

```
from random import randint
s = "test"
#transform to asci
l = ''.join(str(ord(c)) for c in s)
#transform to 1 digit numbers
n = [l[i:i+1] for i in range(0, len(l), 1)]
#make a empty list
r = []
#fill the empty list with new data
while True:
    a = randint(0,9)
    b = randint(0,9)
    for z in n:
        if a+b == z:
            print(''.join(str(a)+str(b)))
            break
        else:
            print('x')
            break
```

What i am trying to do is basically take the ascii code and
split it by 1 digit numbers then those numbers would go like
1 = 0+1 = 01 
2 = 1+1 = 11
i want to loop through the list and check if those statements are true then save them into a new list

Comment: It will never be True as `if a+b ==x` is comparing strings with integers

Comment: Do you want to loop until `a+b ==x` is True? Besides @yatu's comment, the `break` will only allow one loop, and the `while True` will cause an infinite loop. You could set a variable, like `something = False` and then do `while not something`. Then, once `a+b == x` is True, change the variable `something` to True.

Comment: Also, move the `break` to inside the `if` statment, after `z.append(''.join(str(a)+str(b)))`

Comment: I suspect your code copying isn't correct as I believe that Python will choke on the 'else' with only a comment after it.

Comment: what i want is to loop till ```a+b==x``` is true then if its true i want to pass into the next item in the list and do the same thing till i end with another list containing the result and the problem is not with the ```while true``` because i already tried many methods like it i just wanted to mention that one in , the problem is when the if statement it does not repeat the loop till it's true

Comment: Why the `for` loop? You could use `if a + b in n:`. Of course you will need to have numbers in your list `n` and not strings.

Comment: i have updated the code if you could please look at it

Comment: When you set `n` in that list comprehension, wrap the first statement in `int()`: `int(l[i:i+1])` -- that will set you up with numbers instead of strings, which you can then add later in your if statement. n => `[1, 1, 6, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 6]` (whereas before it was n => `['1', '1', '6', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '5', '1', '1', '6']`)

Comment: Seeing your last edit, you might want to do `str(a) + str(b) == x`, and ignore my previous comment about int() in the list comprehension

Comment: the comment above is right i must convert my string to an int because when i want to check if 1 + 3 = x and x is 4 not '13 '

Comment: You can replace `n = [l[i:i+1] for i in range(0, len(l), 1)` with `n = list(l)` and `''.join(str(a)+str(b))` with `str(a)+str(b)`.

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment on it, which you have since deleted. It would have been helpful in this case to provide a description of the output you wanted to generate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your intention was clearest in the earliest version of your question. As far as I can tell, you want to keep generating random digits until you find two that add up to equal one of the digits in your list `n`. Your original code was nearly there, except you were comparing ints to strings, and you needed a way to break out of both loops. The code below should work for you.

```
from random import randint

n = ['1','2','3','5']
z = []
# set a sentinel to break out of both loops when needed
done = False
while not done:
    a = randint(0,9)
    b = randint(0,9)
    for x in n:
        if str(a+b) == x:
            z.append(''.join(str(a)+str(b)))
            # break out of both loops
            done = True
            break
print(z)
# ['21'] or something else
```

I've converted `a+b` to a string, but you may prefer to convert the entries in `n` to ints earlier.

Since the inner loop is only used to check whether the current digits match, you can replace it with Python's `in` operator, like this:

```
from random import randint

n = ['1','2','3','5']
z = []
while True:
    a = randint(0,9)
    b = randint(0,9)
    if str(a+b) in n:
        z.append(str(a)+str(b))  # equivalent to ''.join(str(a)+str(b))
        break
print(z)
# ['50'] or something else
```

## Update

You mentioned in a comment (now missing) that you want to find a matching pair of digits for each element in `n`. To do that with code like you started with, you need to reverse the order of the loops: an outer loop steps through each element of `n` and an inner loop repeats until it finds a suitable pair of digits:

```
from random import randint
n = ['1','2','3','5']
z = []
for x in n:
    while True:
        a = randint(0, 9)
        b = randint(0, 9)
        if a+b == int(x):
            z.append(str(a)+str(b))
            break
print(z)
# ['01', '20', '12', '23'] or similar
```

With this code the first digit of each pair will be uniformly distributed between 0 and `x` and the second digit will always equal `x` minus the first digit. It is more efficient to just generate pairs like that directly, without the inner loop:

```
from random import randint
n = ['1','2','3','5']
z = []
for x in n:
    a = randint(0, int(x))
    b = int(x) - a
    z.append(str(a)+str(b))
print(z)
# ['01', '02', '21', '05'] or similar
```

Comment: Thanks , your solution works best for me , its also much more faster than the solution i found , thank you alot